# How does one determine the size of an unnamed struct?

Tags: c

I'm looking for a way to determine the size of an unnamed struct because I want to explicitly calculate padding.

I have set of structures that have a common a general layout

```
struct Packet {
  uint8_t AllocatorDebugInfo[ALLOC_SIZE /* constant across all structs */ ];
  /* OPTIONAL */ uint8_t Padding[       /* Needs to be determined */      ];
  uint8_t Header[HEADER_SIZE            /* dependent on  packet type */   ];
  uint8_t Payload[PAYLOAD_SIZE          /* constant across all structs*/  ];
};
```

I have the following requirements:

- I have written a special purpose allocator that has debugging information in front of the packet.
- I want exchangeable header types while keeping the payload across all packet types layout compatible.

I'm trying to calculate the Header Size as shown in the code below:

```
typedef union {
  struct { /* opaque */ } SmallHeader;
  struct { /* opaque */ } MedHeader;
  struct { /* opaque */ } LargeHeader;
} HeaderSizes;

HeaderSizes *p;
enum { SMALL_PADDING = sizeof(HeaderSizes) - sizeof(p->SmallHeader)) };
```

Unfortunately memory is tight and I'm looking ways to avoid the global pointer.

#### EDIT:

Apparently trying to calculate an optional padding like this is a very bad idea. This only works as long as you are aware of the fact, that the biggest struct will have more padding than expected (zero).

```
enum { LARGE_PADDING = sizeof (HeaderSizes) - sizeof ((HeaderSizes*)0->LargeHeader) };
struct LargePacket {
  uint8_t AllocDebug[ALLOC_SIZE];
  uint8_t Padding[ LARGE_PADDING ]; /* will evaluate to 0 -- struct size 1 */
  uint8_t Payload[ PAYLOAD_SIZE ];  /* off by 1 */
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator doesn't need a valid instance to return the size. It just needs an expression that evaluates to the correct type. While it's a bit of a hack, you could cast `NULL` to `HeaderSizes*`.

```
sizeof(((HeaderSizes*)NULL)->SmallHeader)
```

Since this isn't dereferencing a null pointer, but is a syntactic construct, the above is perfectly valid and gives a correct result. Such as in the bellow example.

http://ideone.com/QKTOdP

Comment: Using `NULL` instead of `0` would be nicer, however: 1+

Comment: @alk, thanks. I've been doing more C++ these days :)

Comment: The code example in ideaone is a named struct. I thought the question was about computing the `sizeof` of an unnamed struct? For example, this fails: https://asciinema.org/a/nbsd9MQxMOOmM2e73l4SI1o2P you see there is 20 bytes, but `sizeof` does not reflect that.

Comment: @ifelsemonkey - The code example in ideone computes the size of a field via an expression referring to the field. It does not compute the size of the container, so the fact it's a named struct has no bearing